# Drupal 6 - Expand menu items without clicking checkbox

Tags: drupal, menu, navigation, drupal-6

Is there a way to render a menu (in this case 'navigation' (the one with 'create content', 'administer' etc.) with it's children automatically expanded i.e. you don't have to check the expanded checkbox under under the site building > menu area.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is probably no, if installing additional modules is also not an option.

But i too am too lazy for clicking so many checkboxes, and when i just want all items of a menu expanded (all checkboxes checked), i run the following jQuery/Javascript in my browsers' console:

`$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked')`

then the only thing left to do, is clicking the save button..

be aware of the fact that this also checkes the boxes of any disabled menu-items